# How to keep PostgreSQL from disconnecting during a query

Tags: windows, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm running a query in pgAdmin III on Windows that takes a long time and my connection keeps getting lost after about 15 minutes or so. I can't seem to find the script I used before, could anyone help?

Comment: Sounds as if you have a [`statement_timeout`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT) defined

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that

Comment: is it for all queries or a simple `select * from table`  runs smoothly?